# Magento 1: Stop supporting Flash at the end of 2020

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Reference url: https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/saying-goodbye-flash-chrome/

Adobe announced its plans to stop supporting Flash at the end of 2020. And google announced that remove **Flash** completely from Chrome toward the end of 2020.

Still we are using magento1 and image upload depended on flash. if flash removed from chrome, how to upload images in magento 1?

1. is all magento 1 version depended on flash? (currently using 1.9.4.4)
2. is there any patch from magento for this issue?
3. what are the impact on magento 1, if flash removed from browser?
4. what is the solution for the image upload, if flash removed from browser?

Answer (score 1):

As flash player is no longer in service you should move to html5 base uploader

Just follow instructions given in link below, I tested on 1.9.4 and it worked !!!

> **https://www.mavenecommerce.com/2016/10/18/magento-html5-uploader**

Comment: I have installed this module on my site and it works fine for product and CMS Image upload properly
Thank you

Comment: Hi, By uploading this module , on browse of image I get a console error and upload green bar stops at 1/3rd position. Can you please help me for it. 
Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    onreadystatechange https://[siteurl].com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/js/maven_html5upload/script.js:99

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this was resolved in SUPEE 8788 and 1.9.3 release

Core team switched to JS uploader for this reason.

https://support.hypernode.com/en/best-practices/security/how-to-install-magento-patch-supee-8788-and-release-1-9-3

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-8788

APPSEC-666 - Cross-site scripting in Flash file uploader

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've tried non flash uploaders and Magento 1.9.1.0, but nothing worked, but the following worked for me.

1. Upload designs to; /public_html/media/import
2. Import the csv file using ‘Import Product Stocks”. The images will be processed and put into other cached folders, but won't appear on the website.
3. Then put the images into /public_html/STORENAME/media/catalog/product/ and they need go into folder/sub folder where the first/second character of the filename are the folder names.

So if the image is C9256.jpg, put the image in /public_html/STORENAME/media/catalog/product/C/9/

If the image is 3777.jpg, then put the image in /public_html/STORENAME/media/catalog/product/3/7/

Once the third part is done the image will appear on the website.

This worked for me.